# why do i get "return outside function" eventhough my indentation is correct?

Tags: python, return

Does anyone know why I get an indentation error even though it (should) be correct?

```
while not stop:
    try:
        response += sock.recv(buffer_size)
        if header not in response:
            print("error in message format")
            return # this is where I get the error 
    except socket.timeout:
        stop = True
```

Error Code `python3 ueb02.py localhost 31000 File "ueb02.py", line 40 return ^ SyntaxError: 'return' outside function make: *** [run] Error 1`

**edit:** Thanks for the answers, @balderman's approach solved my problem. Thanks to everyone who contributed here :D

Comment: All we have is what you show us, and there is no function in the code you show us. As far as we can tell, that error is correct

Comment: it looks like inside an loop not in function, please put it in a function/method

Comment: Did you mean `break`?

Comment: @DeepSpace what else should I add? it tells me that the error is inside this loop...

Comment: @quamrana no. If i use break, the programm will continue to do things afterwards, which i want to avoid. If the "header is not in response" the programm should end right threre. Break would only leave the loop :(

Comment: @sepæpa ... The error is that you `return` without being inside a function: replace `return` with `break` . You may also `raise` and error since you're in a try-except-clause, if you wish to end up at your `stop = True`. The error is correct, and has nothing to do with indention.

Comment: @magnus I know - it should be break. But there is still code after the loop, which would produce unwanted results if the "header is not in response" .. thats why I wanted to exit the entire programm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `return` only if the code is part of a function.

Use `sys.exit()` if you want to stop the flow of program.

See https://python101.pythonlibrary.org/chapter20_sys.html#sys-exit

Answer (score 1):

You can only `return` values from a function.
To solve your problem, instead of return, you can use a `break` statement and `print` the values.

Comment: I know - it should be break. But there is still code after the loop, which would produce unwanted results if the "header is not in response" .. thats why I wanted to exit the entire programm.

Comment: well in that case as suggested by @balderman, you can use sys.exit().